# Why is my enum value "undefined" when using it as a parameter?

Tags: c++, enums

A simplified model of my problem is below. All I'm trying to do is use the DegreeChecker() function in main(). The DegreeChecker() function takes an enum, 'DegreeProgram', as its type. This enum is defined in its own class, which subsequent classes inherit. But the problem is that the function in main() keeps treating any enum parameter as "undefined". Why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Degree {
public:
    enum DegreeProgram { SECURITY, NETWORK, SOFTWARE };

};

class UseEnum : Degree {
public:
    bool DegreeChecker(DegreeProgram degreeProgram);
};

bool UseEnum::DegreeChecker(DegreeProgram degreeProgram) {

    if (degreeProgram == SOFTWARE) {
        return true;
    }

}



int main()
{
    UseEnum NewDegree;

    NewDegree.DegreeChecker(SOFTWARE); **//error: identifier "SOFTWARE" is undefined -- why?** 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SOFTWARE` is indeed undefined. You probably meant `Degree::SOFTWARE`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Well, that sure works. I was under the impression based on my task's instructions that the parameter had to take only the enum value alone, but to be fair I wouldn't put it past my instructions to just be that unclear.

Answer (score 3):

The symbol is scoped to the `Degree` class so you will need to specify that in order to use it:

```cpp
NewDegree.DegreeChecker(Degree::SOFTWARE);
```

Answer (score 3):

The enum is a member of the `Degree` class, so it needs to be qualified.

Try

```
NewDegree.DegreeChecker(Degree::SOFTWARE);
```